# Adding LESS file to HTML

Tags: less

I have downloaded less.js and trying to include it. Also trying to include a custom button.less file in my HTML code. It is throwing me the below error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\male\OnlineOrder_Pro\styles\button.less" />
<script src="C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\male\OnlineOrder_Pro\less\dist\less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
<div>
<input type='button' value="Submit"/>
</div>
</body>

</head>
</html>
```

LESS file

```
input[type=button] {
      height: 30px;
      width: 70px;
      border: solid 1px rgb(182, 234, 230);
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-image: linear-gradient(210deg, white 30%, rgb(182, 234, 230) 99%);
}
```

above is the less. Should it be wrapped inside a  attribute or it should be the way it is.

ERROR is:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
less.js:413 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/male/OnlineOrder_Pro/styles/button.less. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.doXHR @ less.js:413loadFile @ less.js:470loadStyleSheet @ less.js:627loadStyleSheets @ less.js:638module.exports.less.refresh @ less.js:708module.exports.less.refresh @ less.js:704(anonymous function) @ less.js:84
less.js:413 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/male/OnlineOrder_Pro/styles/button.less'. {message: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Fail…Desktop/male/OnlineOrder_Pro/styles/button.less'.", name: "NetworkError", code: 19, stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest…ktop/male/OnlineOrder_Pro/less/dist/less.js:84:25", INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1…}doXHR @ less.js:413loadFile @ less.js:470loadStyleSheet @ less.js:627loadStyleSheets @ less.js:638module.exports.less.refresh @ less.js:708module.exports.less.refresh @ less.js:704(anonymous function) @ less.js:84
```

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The way you are linking your file is not how you should be doing it, also, you should compile less files before you deploy your website

Comment: How to accomplish that?

Comment: [Google always](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=compile+less+files&oq=compile+less+files)

Comment: Why not try using relative paths?

Comment: Please explain Relative path

Comment: If you get an error that you don't understand, your first step should be to *search* for that error.

Comment: Which browser are you using? If it's Google Chrome, then the local javascript files will not load due to security reasons. You can use a local server like WAMP for this purpose.